# Can't find "live editing of literals" when working with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to find the ' live editing of literals ' menu which should be here -

[image]

The option is enabled via Android Studio settings, I have the latest version installed and I have no clue why I can't see it like it should be in the official documentations -

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#live-edit-literals

Any clues?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#enable-experimental-features

Comment: @PhilipDukhov just checked, everything is ticked to be enabled for me so I have no clue what is it that I am missing

Comment: Have you tried searching preferences? **Editor** -> **Live edit of literals** should be enabled

Comment: @PhilipDukhov it is indeed enabled

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @VikashParajuli nope...

Comment: Same here, fixed it by running the app on an emulator with API Level 30

Answer (score 0):

Live edit of literals
Android Studio can update in real time some constant literals used in composables within previews, emulator, and physical device. Here are some supported types:

Int
String
Color
Dp
Boolean

check the setting do u have Live edit of literals enabled. if you do, you just need to press finger press icon right next to preview run button Icon in your preview screen. It only change above listed types.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have added a new component and it is not yet detected to change live (maybe you copied and pasted it).